# Full Calendar with vertical Resources - Make Day Border More Prominent

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

We're using FullCalendar in the week view with vertical columns of resources for each day.

It's not easy to see where each days starts and ends as the side border is the same for all cells.
Is it possible to style the left border for the last resource for a day ?

Is there CSS or Javascript that'll allow me to set a different left border for the first or last cell in each  sequence of data-date values ?

A table row looks like;

```
<tr>
    <td class="fc-axis fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;"><span>All Day</span></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="2"></td></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="409439">
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="53588">
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you always know that each sequence has exactly 4 cells (tds)? or might some extra cells get added or deleted at run time, e.g. by user action?

Comment: No, there can be one or up to 12 cells for each day.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks:

> Is there CSS or Javascript that'll allow me to set a different left border for the first or last cell in each sequence of data-date values ?

Using just CSS, and regardless of how many cells each day may have, a way of targeting the first cell in each sequence is to look at the set of cells with the same day (.fc-mon,..., .fc-fri). This snippet sets the left border for every cell of these classes and then unsets them for every one of them that is a sibling of a cell with the same class. In this way just the first cells with class .fc-mon,..., . fc-fri are styled.

```html
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 3vw; /* just for this demo */
}

     .fc-mon, .fc-tue, .fc-wed, .fc-thu, .fc-fri {
        border-left: 4px solid black;
    }

     .fc-mon ~ .fc-mon, .fc-tue ~ .fc-tue, .fc-tue ~ .fc-tue, .fc-wed ~ .fc-wed, .fc-thu ~ .fc-thu, .fc-fri ~ .fc-fri     {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="fc-axis fc-widget-content" style="width: 55px;"><span>All Day</span></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today " data-date="2021-08-23" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-08-24" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-08-25" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="2"></td></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="409439"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-08-26" data-resource-id="53588"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="2"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="409439">
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="13"></td>
    <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-08-27" data-resource-id="53588">
</tr>

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks good, does what I want.

Can you explain what '.fc-mon ~ .fc-mon' means ?  I'm not a CSS expert.

Comment: It’s selecting any element with class fc-mon which is also a following sibling of an element with class fc-mon. So the first element with class fc-min isn’t selected. All the others are.

Comment: Hi, I guess this isn't doing what you want, could you describe what problem it presents and I'll have another look?

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS selector `:first-child` or `:last-child` you can target the first/last element. In the below example I have targeted the first and last elements of the table row and applied some background color. You can apply your required styles for the element. But structure is very important to target the element.

```css
#tmp tr td:first-child {
  background:red;
}
#tmp tr td:last-child {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<table id="tmp">
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <td>second</td>
  <td>third</td>
  <td>fourth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <td>second</td>
  <td>third</td>
  <td>fourth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <td>second</td>
  <td>third</td>
  <td>fourth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <td>second</td>
  <td>third</td>
  <td>fourth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>first</td>
  <td>second</td>
  <td>third</td>
  <td>fourth</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The answer's table shows multiple rows, which doesn't reflect the question's table.